# Missing dlls when converting py file to exe

Tags: python-2.7, py2exe

I'm trying to convert my python script and I keep getting the following error:

```
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'libopenblas.TXA6YQSD3GCQQC22GEQ54J2UDCXDXHWN.gfortran-win_amd64.dll'
```

Can someone, please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have NumPy installed?  It appears that files comes with it.

Try: `pip install intel-numpy` or `conda install numpy` depending on which package manager you want to use.

If you already have it installed, and are still getting the error... Identify which folder it is installed in and add that folder to your path before running the exe tool.

Comment: thank you. the compilation was done successfully but when I run the app it comes with this error 'C:\Users\office\Desktop\final\dist\final>final.exe
Traceback (most recent call last): File "final.py", line 4, in <module> File "c:\users\office\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module exec(bytecode, module.__dict__) File "site-packages\rasterio\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
[12532] Failed to execute script final'

Comment: Have you figured out just where that DLL is yet?  This is certainly key to your success.